# How to find the d' Alembert solution?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Find d’Alembert’s solution to the problem:

$\frac{∂^2u}{∂t^2} =\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} ,x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t > 0$

$u(x, 0) = x^2  \in \mathbb{R}$

$\frac{∂u}{∂t} (x, 0) = 0 ,x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My attempt : I thin $u(x,t)$ will be $0 $  because $u(x,0)=u'(x,0)=0$

Any Hints/solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a straightforward application of d'Alembert's formula: $$u(x,t) = \frac{(x+t)^2 +(x-t)^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t}0\,{\rm d}s = x^2+t^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

There is a forlmula.[D'Alembert' forlmula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula)